# Rewrite url IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I want to made url rewrite on a IIS server.
Actually my url is:

```
localhost/Pages/Doctor/index.aspx
```

and i want to trasform to

```
localhost/Doctor/index
```

How I can configure my Web.config files for doing this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As a helpful bit of advice, questions on this site usually get more attention if you can be more specific / detailed. Have you tried anything in your Web.config? Is there something in the IIS redirect documentation you don't understand? The more information you provide, the better!

Comment: i've read IIS documentation but i don't understand what are dthe difference between redirect and rewrite roles